# Possible Macro Definiton Clash with Arduino Core Library

Tags: arduino, macros, arduino-c++, name-clash

I have a `CanUtils.h` header file and a `CanUtils.cpp` source file, organized in the following directory tree:

```
Documents
|---Arduino
| |---libraries
|  |--- CanUtils 
|   |--- CanUtils.h
    |--- CanUtils.cpp
```

These files make up the *CanUtils* library I'm trying to create. The contents of `CanUtils.h` are as follows:

```
#ifndef CanUtils_h
#define CanUtils_h

enum PRIORITY_LEVEL 
{
 LOW     = 6
};
#endif
```

While the contents of `CanUtils.cpp` are as follows:

```
#include "CanUtils.h"
```

As you can see, it is really simple, but when I just try to include the library using the following test script:

```
#include <CanUtils.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I get the following error log after compiling:

In file included from C:\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\FB4D0CAE5653D98D753CBC42EE69409D\sketch\library_tests.ino.cpp:1:0:
C:AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:41:14: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 #define LOW 0x0
       ^
C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\CanUtils/CanUtils.h:7:3: note: in expansion of macro 'LOW'
  LOW     = 6
  ^~~
C:\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:41:14: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
 #define LOW 0x0
       ^
C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\CanUtils/CanUtils.h:7:3: note: in expansion of macro 'LOW'
  LOW     = 6
  ^~~
C:\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:41:14: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 #define LOW 0x0
       ^
C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\CanUtils/CanUtils.h:7:3: note: in expansion of macro 'LOW'
  LOW     = 6
  ^~~
In file included from C:\Users\PC-LENOVO\Downloads\library_tests\library_tests.ino:1:0:
C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\CanUtils/CanUtils.h:8:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
 };
 ^

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1//i.stack.imgur.com/EbLqZ.png

I'm not sure where the error can be...From the error log it looks like there's gotta be some sort of macro definition clash with a core Arduino library when attempting to use the keyword "LOW" in an enum.  Going to that same file indicated by the error log shows there is a definition in Arduino.h for the keyword LOW:

```
/*
  Arduino.h - Main include file for the Arduino SDK
  Copyright (c) 2005-2013 Arduino Team.  All right reserved.

  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
  Lesser General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

#ifndef Arduino_h
#define Arduino_h

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#include "binary.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

void yield(void);

#define HIGH 0x1
#define LOW  0x0

#define INPUT 0x0
#define OUTPUT 0x1
#define INPUT_PULLUP 0x2

#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#define HALF_PI 1.5707963267948966192313216916398
#define TWO_PI 6.283185307179586476925286766559
#define DEG_TO_RAD 0.017453292519943295769236907684886
#define RAD_TO_DEG 57.295779513082320876798154814105
#define EULER 2.718281828459045235360287471352

#define SERIAL  0x0
#define DISPLAY 0x1

#define LSBFIRST 0
#define MSBFIRST 1

#define CHANGE 1
#define FALLING 2
#define RISING 3

#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny24__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny44__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny84__)
  #define DEFAULT 0
  #define EXTERNAL 1
  #define INTERNAL1V1 2
  #define INTERNAL INTERNAL1V1
#elif defined(__AVR_ATtiny25__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny45__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__)
  #define DEFAULT 0
  #define EXTERNAL 4
  #define INTERNAL1V1 8
  #define INTERNAL INTERNAL1V1
  #define INTERNAL2V56 9
  #define INTERNAL2V56_EXTCAP 13
#else  
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega1284__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega1284P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega644__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega644A__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega644P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega644PA__)
#define INTERNAL1V1 2
#define INTERNAL2V56 3
#else
#define INTERNAL 3
#endif
#define DEFAULT 1
#define EXTERNAL 0
#endif

// undefine stdlib's abs if encountered
#ifdef abs
#undef abs
#endif

#define min(a,b) ((a)<(b)?(a):(b))
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
#define abs(x) ((x)>0?(x):-(x))
#define constrain(amt,low,high) ((amt)<(low)?(low):((amt)>(high)?(high):(amt)))
#define round(x)     ((x)>=0?(long)((x)+0.5):(long)((x)-0.5))
#define radians(deg) ((deg)*DEG_TO_RAD)
#define degrees(rad) ((rad)*RAD_TO_DEG)
#define sq(x) ((x)*(x))

#define interrupts() sei()
#define noInterrupts() cli()

#define clockCyclesPerMicrosecond() ( F_CPU / 1000000L )
#define clockCyclesToMicroseconds(a) ( (a) / clockCyclesPerMicrosecond() )
#define microsecondsToClockCycles(a) ( (a) * clockCyclesPerMicrosecond() )

#define lowByte(w) ((uint8_t) ((w) & 0xff))
#define highByte(w) ((uint8_t) ((w) >> 8))

#define bitRead(value, bit) (((value) >> (bit)) & 0x01)
#define bitSet(value, bit) ((value) |= (1UL << (bit)))
#define bitClear(value, bit) ((value) &= ~(1UL << (bit)))
#define bitToggle(value, bit) ((value) ^= (1UL << (bit)))
#define bitWrite(value, bit, bitvalue) ((bitvalue) ? bitSet(value, bit) : bitClear(value, bit))

// avr-libc defines _NOP() since 1.6.2
#ifndef _NOP
#define _NOP() do { __asm__ volatile ("nop"); } while (0)
#endif

typedef unsigned int word;

#define bit(b) (1UL << (b))

typedef bool boolean;
typedef uint8_t byte;

void init(void);
void initVariant(void);

int atexit(void (*func)()) __attribute__((weak));

void pinMode(uint8_t pin, uint8_t mode);
void digitalWrite(uint8_t pin, uint8_t val);
int digitalRead(uint8_t pin);
int analogRead(uint8_t pin);
void analogReference(uint8_t mode);
void analogWrite(uint8_t pin, int val);

unsigned long millis(void);
unsigned long micros(void);
void delay(unsigned long ms);
void delayMicroseconds(unsigned int us);
unsigned long pulseIn(uint8_t pin, uint8_t state, unsigned long timeout);
unsigned long pulseInLong(uint8_t pin, uint8_t state, unsigned long timeout);

void shiftOut(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val);
uint8_t shiftIn(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder);

void attachInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNum, void (*userFunc)(void), int mode);
void detachInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNum);

void setup(void);
void loop(void);

// Get the bit location within the hardware port of the given virtual pin.
// This comes from the pins_*.c file for the active board configuration.

#define analogInPinToBit(P) (P)

// On the ATmega1280, the addresses of some of the port registers are
// greater than 255, so we can't store them in uint8_t's.
extern const uint16_t PROGMEM port_to_mode_PGM[];
extern const uint16_t PROGMEM port_to_input_PGM[];
extern const uint16_t PROGMEM port_to_output_PGM[];

extern const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_port_PGM[];
// extern const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_bit_PGM[];
extern const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_bit_mask_PGM[];
extern const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_timer_PGM[];

// Get the bit location within the hardware port of the given virtual pin.
// This comes from the pins_*.c file for the active board configuration.
// 
// These perform slightly better as macros compared to inline functions
//
#define digitalPinToPort(P) ( pgm_read_byte( digital_pin_to_port_PGM + (P) ) )
#define digitalPinToBitMask(P) ( pgm_read_byte( digital_pin_to_bit_mask_PGM + (P) ) )
#define digitalPinToTimer(P) ( pgm_read_byte( digital_pin_to_timer_PGM + (P) ) )
#define analogInPinToBit(P) (P)
#define portOutputRegister(P) ( (volatile uint8_t *)( pgm_read_word( port_to_output_PGM + (P))) )
#define portInputRegister(P) ( (volatile uint8_t *)( pgm_read_word( port_to_input_PGM + (P))) )
#define portModeRegister(P) ( (volatile uint8_t *)( pgm_read_word( port_to_mode_PGM + (P))) )

#define NOT_A_PIN 0
#define NOT_A_PORT 0

#define NOT_AN_INTERRUPT -1

#ifdef ARDUINO_MAIN
#define PA 1
#define PB 2
#define PC 3
#define PD 4
#define PE 5
#define PF 6
#define PG 7
#define PH 8
#define PJ 10
#define PK 11
#define PL 12
#endif

#define NOT_ON_TIMER 0
#define TIMER0A 1
#define TIMER0B 2
#define TIMER1A 3
#define TIMER1B 4
#define TIMER1C 5
#define TIMER2  6
#define TIMER2A 7
#define TIMER2B 8

#define TIMER3A 9
#define TIMER3B 10
#define TIMER3C 11
#define TIMER4A 12
#define TIMER4B 13
#define TIMER4C 14
#define TIMER4D 15
#define TIMER5A 16
#define TIMER5B 17
#define TIMER5C 18

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include "WCharacter.h"
#include "WString.h"
#include "HardwareSerial.h"
#include "USBAPI.h"
#if defined(HAVE_HWSERIAL0) && defined(HAVE_CDCSERIAL)
#error "Targets with both UART0 and CDC serial not supported"
#endif

uint16_t makeWord(uint16_t w);
uint16_t makeWord(byte h, byte l);

#define word(...) makeWord(__VA_ARGS__)

unsigned long pulseIn(uint8_t pin, uint8_t state, unsigned long timeout = 1000000L);
unsigned long pulseInLong(uint8_t pin, uint8_t state, unsigned long timeout = 1000000L);

void tone(uint8_t _pin, unsigned int frequency, unsigned long duration = 0);
void noTone(uint8_t _pin);

// WMath prototypes
long random(long);
long random(long, long);
void randomSeed(unsigned long);
long map(long, long, long, long, long);

#endif

#include "pins_arduino.h"

#endif
```

Is there any way to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Keywords are constants, variables and function names that are defined as part of the Arduino language. Avoid using keywords for variable names." (extracted from: [https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~fgeorg/250a/lab2/arduino-0019/reference/Keywords.html](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Efgeorg/250a/lab2/arduino-0019/reference/Keywords.html)). It turns out "LOW" is one of those keywords...

Comment: yes and a pretty visible one. as in digtalWrite(pin, LOW)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. It didn't occur to me because I thought being inside its own namespace and inside its enum it wouldn't affect it, but it looks like it does.

Comment: There's nothing like a namespace for macros.